# post BOOL to JSON using AFNetworking 3.X ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking-3

AFNetworking don't want to represent BOOL value as true/false in JSON request. Tried @YES, NSNumber but no chance, it converts to 0 or 1.

```
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[data setValue:@YES forKey:@"favorite"];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:data forKey:@"data"];
```

then giving this param dictionary to AfNetworking 3

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

manager.requestSerializer = serializer;


[manager POST:@"HTTPS://JSON URL" parameters:params progress:^(NSProgress *uploadProgress) {
} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * task, id responseObject) {
//SUCCESS
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
//FAILED REQUEST
}];
```

Comment: The way to put a boolean into a dictionary is to use an NSNumber like you are doing. I have done this for every time I have ever interacted with JSON. It works. Why do you think it is not working?

Comment: i am logging "params" with NSLog and there is 0 or 1

Comment: Yes, that is what it will look like. Why is that a problem? That's what it should look like.

Comment: But in the JSON output I need favorite: true or false, not 1 or 0

Comment: If you want to see whether it puts "true" or "false" into the JSON data, read the JSON data, not the NSLog output. The difference between @YES and @1 is very subtle, but NSJSONSerialization will know it.

Comment: Do you know how to catch raw post JSON data in AFNetworkin 3?

Comment: Have you tried it and actually seen it not work? Or are you just assuming it won't work? This works.

Comment: I will check with server. Thank you for help!

Comment: If you truly need the values to be either "true" or "false" (and it sounds like this is a content decision governed by the server, not anything inherent in the JSON specification), you probably need to be explicit about that in your `data` dictionary.  In your example, where you've hard-coded @YES for the value, try `[data setValue:@"true" forKey:@"favorite"];`

Answer (score 0):

Use `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've been toggling booleans, then sending them as JSON booleans using AFNetworking:

```
    self.petActive = ! self.petActive;
    NSNumber* newFMPstate = self.petActive ? @YES : @NO;
    NSDictionary *fmpDict = @{ @"petActive": newFMPstate };
    /// ... assemble endpoint for put and pass it fmpDict
```

@YES and @NO respectively generate this JSON

```
{"petActive":true}  
{"petActive":false}
```

(I know the ternary operator is redundant, but it seems to add readability)